# Remote access of sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-administration, configurationmanager

I have got a remote server from client, and having sql server there connecting through local host.

Now I need to connect it through my local pc management studio.

What I need to do, Do I need any step up, or is there any place where I can find connection string to connect through remote.

Please advise.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

To connect from your PC to a remote SQL instance, you will need the remote server's external IP plus the usual instance name and credentials

[image]

You will need to ensure that Firewalls etc are configured correctly on the remote server as per the link posted by scsimon

Comment: is this remote server ip or something else

Comment: its the WAN IP of the network the remote server is on (go to www.whatismyip.com) on the remote server to get this (assuming no VPNs etc)

Comment: The remote server's network will need to be configured to forward traffic on the port SQL sever is using (1433 by default) to the remote server itself

Comment: This needs to be accepted and closed. This question lacks initial research effort.